# In sql server how to get get All Month and year from given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to display all months names ,month number and year in a query.

Suppose my given date is

> @date=’ 2003-03-01’

My desired out put is bellow:

[image]

Help me to fix my My bellow sql syntax.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2003-03-01',
        @inc INT = 0
;with cte as
(
    select 
    @inc AS Inc,
    DATENAME(mm,@Date) AS [MonthName],
    DATEPART(mm,@Date) AS [MonthNumber],
    DATEPART(yy,@Date) as [MonthYear]
    UNION ALL
    select
     inc+1,
     DATENAME(mm,DATEADD(mm,inc+1,@Date)),
     DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(mm,inc+1,@Date)),
     DATEPART(yy,@date) 
    FROM cte
    where inc < 12
)
select [MonthName],[MonthNumber],[MonthYear] from cte
```

If have any query please ask,Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2003-03-01',
        @inc INT = 0
;with cte as
(
    SELECT Inc              = @inc                 
          ,[MonthName]      = DATENAME(mm ,@Date)  
          ,[MonthNumber]    = DATEPART(mm ,@Date)  
          ,[MonthYear]      = DATEPART(yy ,@Date)  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT inc + 1
          ,DATENAME(mm ,DATEADD(mm ,inc + 1 ,@Date))
          ,DATEPART(mm ,DATEADD(mm ,inc + 1 ,@Date))
          ,CASE WHEN [MonthNumber] = 12 THEN [MonthYear] + 1 ELSE [MonthYear] END
    FROM    cte
    WHERE  inc < 12
)
select [MonthName],[MonthNumber],[MonthYear] from cte
```

This might be a simpler pattern though;

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2003-03-01'
;WITH MoreSimple as
(
    SELECT   [MonthName]    = DATENAME(mm ,@Date)  
            ,[MonthNumber]  = DATEPART(mm ,@Date)  
            ,[MonthYear]    = DATEPART(yy ,@Date) 
            ,NextRow        = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   DATENAME(mm ,NextRow)
            ,DATEPART(mm ,NextRow)
            ,DATEPART(yy ,NextRow)
            ,DATEADD(MONTH, 1, NextRow)
    FROM    MoreSimple
)
SELECT   TOP(100)
         [MonthName]
        ,[MonthNumber]
        ,[MonthYear] 
FROM MoreSimple
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)


----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for getting the year is only using the original date.  Use the `dateadd()` result instead:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2003-03-01',
        @inc INT = 0
;with cte as
(
    select 
    @inc AS Inc,
    DATENAME(mm,@Date) AS [MonthName],
    DATEPART(mm,@Date) AS [MonthNumber],
    DATEPART(yy,@Date) as [MonthYear]
    UNION ALL
    select
     inc+1,
     DATENAME(mm,DATEADD(mm,inc+1,@Date)),
     DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(mm,inc+1,@Date)),
     DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(mm,inc+1,@Date)) 
    FROM cte
    where inc < 12
)
select [MonthName],[MonthNumber],[MonthYear] from cte
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff,thanks for your reply,i also want to get month start date end end date